Identify 80' sf/horror: guy with a gun on his hand
I don't remember much: a guy with a big gun/cannon attached to his hand (his hand was inside the tube). Cannon wasn't an ordinary gun, I guess he found it in some space ship, I'm not sure. I remember a scene when guy is walking through some kind of desert, sunny place. And a last thing: the cannon had a bad influence on the guy. He wasn't feeling good for sure.

Was it Laserblast, (1978)?

A green-skinned man wanders through the desert with a laser cannon
  attached to his arm. A spaceship lands and two aliens emerge, one of
  whom shoots the man, which disintegrates his body. The aliens depart
  on their spaceship, leaving behind the laser cannon and a metallic
  pendant the man was wearing.
...
Billy wanders into the desert and discovers the laser cannon and
  pendant. He starts playing with the cannon, pretending to shoot
  things, then realizes he can fire the weapon while wearing the
  pendant.
...
The next day, Kathy puts the pendant on Billy's chest while they are
  laying together outside. Billy immediately wakes up with green skin
  and deformed teeth and attacks Kathy. Billy goes on a rampage,
  shooting random objects with the laser cannon.


exactly! this was the Laserblast, thanks.

Please mark as answer @Jakub.
